# Controller is not called in angular ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling rest service in my controller to get the values like first name and last name etc but its not returning any values.

Here is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('profileController', function ($scope, $http) {

    var url = 'rs/FetchProfile';
    $http.get(url).success(function (response)
    {
        $scope.profiles = response;
        console.log($scope.profiles); //prints nothing       
    }).error(function (response)
    {
        console.log("error", response);
    });
});
```

The controller is not returning any values. Here is the html code where `ng-controller="profileController"` is declared inside `LoggedIn.hmtl`

```
<div ng-controller="profileController" >
    <div ng-repeat="x in profiles" class="col-lg-4 reduce-left-margin-80">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li>First name and Last name</li>
            <li>position xxxxxxx xxxxxxx</li>
            <li>Company xxxxxx xxx xxxxx</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email address</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My main html page is like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>RTH - Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <!--header-->
            <div ui-view="header"></div>
            <!--main content-->
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>
        <!--footer-->
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>
        <!-- script tags here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And stateprovider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('first', {
        url: "/first",
        views: {
            header: header,
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'views/HomePage.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            footer: footer
        }
    })
    .state('LoggedIn', {
        url: "/LoggedIn",
        views: {
            'header': header,
            'content': {
                temlateUrl: 'views/LoggedIn.html',
                controller: function () {
                }
            },
            'footer': footer
        }
    });
});
```

Do I have to define second state as well for my profile controller to be called?

Comment: in the $stateProvider, you dont define that it corresponds to 'profileController', you are creating a new controller with `controller: function ($scope) {}`

Comment: Have you tried to make rest api call through other tool?

Comment: You have to replace "controller; function($scope) { }" with "controller: 'profileController'"

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant still the same.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes I tried with postman(chrome rest plugin) and its returning values on GET request but its not returning any thing in my app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744133/ui-router-integrating-with-existing-controllers

Comment: One thing that I already see that is wrong is that you should get the data of the response. So $scope.profiles = response.data;. It would be a lot easier to help you if you could create a plunkr.

Comment: @DaanvanHulst response.data is not required

Comment: Do you see any error in your Dev Tools console ?

Comment: @Arkantos There are no errors

Comment: check the response of your GET request in DevTools-Network tab. See if you're getting expected response ?

Comment: @Arkantos No there is no response in network tab or in console. I am guessing `profileController` is not being fired because using postman(rest tool for chrome) I can see the response of @Get method

Comment: @Arkantos one more point I have to mention is that I am loading the `LoggedIn.html' page manually in the browser. Does it have to go through states for the controller to be fired?

Comment: Is `LoggedIn.html` a partial page like your `HomePage.html` which has to be included in your `content` view of your Main html page ?

Comment: @Arkantos exactly you are right. The header and footer are common pages and the `LoggedIn.html` is like dynamic content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99465/discussion-between-arkantos-and-satyadev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your router config. It should be `templateUrl` instead of `temlateUrl`.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('profile', {
        url: "/profile",
        views: {
            header: header,
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'views/LoggedIn.html',
                controller: 'profileController'
            },
            footer: footer
        }
    })
});
```